# auth error when connecting to mongo from c# client

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
mongo:
  container_name: Mongo
  image: mongo
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin 
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
mongo-express:
  image: mongo-express
  container_name: MongoExpress
  environment:
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=user
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
```

I use the following connection string: mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017

But it says:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.
> ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..

Comment: The error says what is wrong, authentication failed.. Ie you should check this part, I vote for credentials related issue

Comment: Yes, credential issue. But where I should look for the error? According to the compose file, usernam and password are correct.

Comment: Check the mongod log, it should report the username and auth database that failed.  Make sure that is what you expected it to be.